# OrientDB " Error on moving existent database"

Tags: docker, orientdb

I'm trying to setup OrientDB distributed configuration with docker. But I'm getting error when starting second node -

> 2015-10-09 17:14:14:066 WARNI
>   [node1444321499719]->[[node1444321392311]] requesting deploy of
>   database 'testDB' on local server... [OHazelcastPlugin] 2015-10-09
>   17:14:14:117 INFO  [node1444321499719]<-[node1444321392311] received
>   updated status node1444321499719.testDB=SYNCHRONIZING
>   [OHazelcastPlugin] 2015-10-09 17:14:14:119 INFO 
>   [node1444321499719]<-[node1444321392311] received updated status
>   node1444321392311.testDB=SYNCHRONIZING [OHazelcastPlugin] 2015-10-09
>   17:14:15:935 WARNI [node1444321499719] moving existent database
>   'testDB' located in '/orientdb/databases/testDB' to
>   '/orientdb/databases/../backup/databases/testDB' and get a fresh copy
>   from a remote node... [OHazelcastPlugin] 2015-10-09 17:14:15:936 SEVER
>   [node1444321499719] error on moving existent database 'testDB' located
>   in '/orientdb/databases/testDB' to
>   '/orientdb/databases/../backup/databases/testDB'. Try to move the
>   database directory manually and retry
>   [OHazelcastPlugin][node1444321499719] Error on starting distributed
>   plugin
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedException:
>   Error on moving existent database 'testDB' located in
>   '/orientdb/databases/testDB' to
>   '/orientdb/databases/../backup/databases/testDB'. Try to move the
>   database directory manually and retry
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.backupCurrentDatabase(OHazelcastPlugin.java:1007)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.requestDatabase(OHazelcastPlugin.java:954)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.installDatabase(OHazelcastPlugin.java:893)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.installNewDatabases(OHazelcastPlugin.java:1426)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.startup(OHazelcastPlugin.java:184)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.registerPlugins(OServer.java:979)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:346)
>           at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain.main(OServerMain.java:41)

I don't have this error if I'm starting orientdb cluster without docker.
Also I can move it in container

> [root@64f6cc1eba61 orientdb]# mv -v /orientdb/databases/testDB
>   /orientdb/databases/../backup/databases/testDB
>   '/orientdb/databases/testDB' ->
>   '/orientdb/databases/../backup/databases/testDB'
>   '/orientdb/databases/testDB/distributed-config.json' ->
>   '/orientdb/databases/../backup/databases/testDB/distributed-config.json'
>   removed '/orientdb/databases/testDB/distributed-config.json' removed
>   directory: '/orientdb/databases/testDB' [root@64f6cc1eba61 orientdb]#
>   ls -l /orientdb/databases/../backup/databases/testDB total 4
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 455 Oct  9 11:32 distributed-config.json [root@64f6cc1eba61 orientdb]#

I'm using OrientDB version 2.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was reported and fixed:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/4891

Set the 'distributed.backupDirectory' variable to a specific directory and the issue should be gone.

By the way, running orient distributed in docker is our experience currently a no go:
- Docker does not support multicast yet, you can work around it, but it's painful. But the main problem:
- Docker doesn't reuse ip addresses on restart, so a container restart will give it a new ip address, this messes up your cluster big time.

We abandoned using orient distributed with docker until docker is fixed on both issues (I believe it is both on the roadmap).

If you experience otherwise, I'm happy to hear your thoughts.

Comment: That helps, thank you. I set it before, but use wrong variable. By the way, about docker, we use docker parameter net=host, so docker use hosts IP, where multicast works fine.

Comment: ah ok, that was not an option for us (can't remember why though).